# Kotlin update readonly map if key is absent

Tags: kotlin

Just curious if there is a better as I ended up with an extension function:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.addIfAbsent(key: K, f: (K) -> V): Map<K, V> =
    when {
        containsKey(key) -> this
        else -> this + (key to f.invoke(key))
    }
```

Comment: Java Maps (so Kotlin as well) do have `putIfAbsent` and `computeIfAbsent` methods built-in. Have yopu considered using those?

Comment: `addIfAbsent()` is a confusing method name for this, as it sounds like it's updating the map in place.  A noun-based name like `addedIfAbsent()`, or even better `plusIfAbsent()`, would be more consistent with Kotlin naming conventions for a method which returns an updated copy.

Comment: @JohannesH.  sadly, putIfAbsent/computeIfAbsent are missing from read-only maps.  Part of my question was checking if I missed the read-only version as it seemed like a no-brainer for library designers.   I'm still getting use to the 'read-only' versus immutable design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is not thread-safe. The original map is read-only from your own function's point of view, but could actually be a MutableMap. The original map could be modified by a different thread between checking and adding. For example, `containsKey(key)` returns false, then the original map is modified and the key is removed, and then your function returns `this`, which doesn't contain the key, even though your function is supposed to guarantee that the key exists after it's called.

For a more concrete version, check first whether the receiver is really mutable:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.plusIfAbsent(key: K, f: (K) -> V): Map<K, V> =
    when {
         this is MutableMap<*, *> -> toMutableMap().apply { getOrPut(key, f) }

         containsKey(key) -> this

         else -> this + (key to f(key))
    }
```

If a map is mutable (such as `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap`) then it will implement the `MutableMap` interface. The copy is only necessary for mutable maps.

When the map is mutable and already contains the key, a copy of it is still made for safety, which can be a performance overhead for single-threaded applications.

Comment: Thanks for that.   The lack of fully immutable data structures does create some complications that I didn't consider.

Comment: @Kurt It just dawned on me that we can actually check if the map really is mutable, and only make the copy when it's necessary.